# Argument of a product of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

I am trying to confirm the following two functions are in fact the same.
[image]
I understand that you add the arguments when you multiply complex numbers. However, I’m unable to turn the top equation into the bottom. I have been using the formula

$$\arg(z)= \frac{1}{2i}\log (z/\bar{z})$$

But still somethings not quite right.

Comment: I believe the argument of $\pi^{it/2}=\ln(\pi)t/2$ and so if it really is an addition of arguments then I have no idea where the subtraction has come from, unless the two arguments have somehow wrapped round to be greater than $2\pi$

Comment: If $t$ is real, then since $\pi^{it/2} = e^{\ln(\pi) i t/2}$, $\ln(\pi) t/2$ is an argument of $\pi^{it/2}$.  You could add any integer multiple of $2\pi$ to this, as arg is multivalued.

Comment: There is a typo in the second definition. The "-" should be "+". Your "arg" formula should be divided by 2.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thank you

Comment: @Andrew23 I am confused why this older question has been given a bounty and re-activated - do you want someone to show the argument using your formula $(1/2i)\ln(z/\overline z)$?

Comment: Yes. I couldn’t figure it out.

Comment: @Andrew23, don't you agree there is a mistake there? (that a "+" should be instead of a "-")